# Open water swimming in the Saarland?

Tags: germany, swimming

With summer finally here, I've been looking for places to swim. There are plenty of public swimming pools, but they're crowded and not as fun as swimming in lakes and rivers.

Where are legal and safe places to do so in the Saarland?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you have nailed it pretty well because Saarland is the smallest non-city state in Germany and there are not many lakes.

- Bostalsee in 66625 Nohfelden. Very nice lake with several smaller lakes in vicinity.
- Stausee Losheim in 66679 Losheim am See.

River quality has improved so much that bathing and swimming should be no problem, even in the Saar.

Bathing in rivers is [normally legal](http://www.wsa-duisburg-meiderich.wsv.de/aktuelles/Baden_im_Kanal), but there are exceptions:

- Forbidden is bathing in vicinity (less than 100 m) of a construction: a bridge, a weir or a lock.
- Also forbidden (trespassing) is bathing if you enter private ground or use a private road.
- While very beautiful, bathing in nature reserves (*Naturschutzgebiet*) is forbidden. Look for this signs because the roads are often free:

[image: Naturschutzgebiet]

- Be careful that you choose locations with weak currents and no high banks. Look out for river traffic because shipping is used extensively in Germany.

Comment: According to http://www.saarland.de/103138.htm, the only official swimming place on a river in Saarland is somewhere on the Nied river, and it has been closed down for several years because of bacterial contamination. Other rivers aren't checked by the authorities.

Answer (score 5):

The Bostalsee and the Losheimer See are indeed nice spots. But you may also consider a trip across the border to [Remerschen](https://www.google.be/maps/place/Remerschen,+Luxemburg/@49.4877468,6.3497437,15z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x47951564a24ec24f:0x476b1d28c61c6baf). There are [lakes where swimming is legal and safe](http://www.schengen-tourist.lu/index.php?idnavigation=30&fidlanguage=1).

From Saarbrücken it is a 45 minutes drive. More or less the same as if you drive to the Bostalsee or the Losheimer See. Depending on where you live in the Saarland, Remerschen might even be closer.

Comment: By car it's not much difference, but by train and bike Bostalsee seems much more accessible. Thanks for the suggestion, though -- it looks nice.

Comment: It depends from where ...

Comment: Of course, sorry! We'll be travelling from Saarbrücken.

Comment: Then you are probably right. As you have a bike, look at this. Travel from Saarbrücken to Nennig on public transport. Then cross the border to Remich. Then head some 5 kilometers southwards along the Moselle. There is a cycle path and the terrain is flat.

Comment: In your case the Bostalsee is the first choice. The regional express from Saarbrücken to Frankfurt passes nearby: station Türkismühle, some 45 minutes from Saarbrücken. And as you plan to take a bike you can easily close the remaining gap and reach the lake.